# missing value # in fastapi

Tags: python, fastapi

have a query string that sends something like search=abc and funny thing is this works but when send

```
search=#### <--- this will result empty in fastapi debug for the search parameter something like empty string ''

if i pass search=@$%#$$ <--- everything after # will be missing and fastapi only gets @S%
```

my frontend is passing # as something like this

```
search=%23%23%23%23%23%23
```

i cant find any reason why fastapi is filtering out the # in this case also i am going through 2 services before hitting my last services part that shows empty ''. my first services interacts with the frontend and i received the # text and first services passing to 2nd services with `request.query_string` where this seems to be making it missing

Comment: `#` is used to denote a local anchor in HTML links. It's never transmitted to the server, and anything after it gets dropped. This can also be the cause of any service or proxy between your frontend and the FastAPI, depending on how each step is configured. You'll have to provide an actual working example without any of the in-between dependencies to show whether it's a javascript/fastapi/html-issue or an issue with the proxies in between.